# PHP: descending asort doesn't work?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

I have this website using arrays and then I have this function which sorts these arrays using `asort`. It looks like this:

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
```

This algorithm sorts the array from 1-10 but I'll need it to sort descending, from 10-1. I have tried using `rsort` with no luck, and I have tried `array_reverse` too without luck. I don't know if I have used them wrong? Or.. Well at least I just need the algorithm to sort them descending. Any idea, advice or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @AzizSaleh he is using builtin `asort`. His custom function has a name `aasort`.

Comment: What does your array look like? @ElmoVanKielmo Saw your response after I removed the message. You are correct, it is a custom sort.

Comment: Looking at your logic, changing `asort($sorter)` to `arsort($sorter)` should work. If it is not, we need to see the $array to understand why its not.

Comment: Thanks @AzizSaleh, the code seems to work as it should now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `usort` with defined ordering function as the documentation says.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function sortSomething($a, $b){
    if ($a < $b){
        return -1;
    }
    else if ($a > $b){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
};
// Now sort the array using the comparison function
usort($array, 'sortSomething');
```

This sorts elements in a normal way - just switch the comparison operators and you'll get reverse sorting.

Comment: however usort takes two parameters, and if I try that instead of `aasort`, it says that I can't redeclare it.

Comment: Oh man. Sure it takes two parameters! One is the array to sort and the second one is the name of the function which compares two elements and returns -1 if first element is less than the second one, 1 if the first element is greater than the second one and 0 if they are equal. It's the same in all languages. The only PHP weirdness is that it takes comparison function name as a string and not the function instance. Don't you understand?

Comment: yeah but will I have to create such a function then, in order to descend it?

Comment: Is this a problem? It's just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: It's no problem, I am just a little bit curious, but actually. change `asort` to `arsort` should fix the problem as well right, so I guess that's a better approach, thanks a lot though!

Comment: Happy to hear it. I thought your sorting logic might be a bit more complicated i.e. based on some attributes of elements of array. Nevertheless if you don't want to accept my answer, a little upvote would be appreciated though :)

Comment: oh yeah well I guess this is a solution too, soo :) have a good day!